# How to adjust for differences between 32 and 64 bit Excel VBA date handling?

Tags: vba, excel

#### Problem:

64 bit Excel VBA has a nasty habit of converting array dates to numbers when that array is assigned to a range. 32 bit VBA, on the other hand, preserves the date format.

#### Example:

Here's a quick bit of example code to demonstrate the different date handling:

```
Sub test()
    Dim arr(0 to 1) As Variant
    arr(0) = "Text"
    arr(1) = #9/12/2007#
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1:B1") = arr
End Sub
```

*(Note that the dates are not converted in 64 bit Excel if a single date value is used; it is necessary to have the first text value present)*

#### Results:

When run in 32 bit Excel, the output is `Text, 9/12/2007`

When run in 64 bit Excel, the output is `Text, 39337`

It is as though 64 bit VBA only uses the Value2 property for all range objects.

#### Question:

How can I get 64 bit VBA to behave like 32 bit VBA without writing a function to handle all array writes?

Just to head off a possible well-intentioned response: I am aware that the underlying formula remains the same between those cells. 32 bit Excel, however, automatically sets the proper cells to a date format which greatly simplifies my code.

Comment: are you sure it's not just a matter of the 64 bit XL not formatting the cell automatically for you? I ask that because the "date value" in excel for 9/12/2007 is `39337`. For all intents and purposes it will read that value as a date for any functions used off it. All probably need to do is tell Excel to format it as such, either in the program, or through VBA. See this for more on Dates and Times in Excel http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/ExcelDateandTimes.htm

Comment: @Scott Holtzmann: This is exactly what is happening, although Excel does not treat numbers as dates unless they are formatted as such. 32 bit Excel automatically formats these cells appropriately so no extra work is required, 64 bit does not. So how can one force 64 bit Excel to behave like 32 bit?

Comment: I may have to bow out after this, because I am not well versed on 64 vs 32 bit excel, but could you just run the range and format any dates as such with some testing. I know it's a ugly solution... but it may be the only.

Comment: That would be _a_ solution, just not the ideal one. I currently have a large set of data that I'm running this macro on each week. Testing each cell, I think, would slow down the macro to unmanageable speeds and I would have to change every range=array statement to some custom function (which is not a trivial change in a macro as large as I have). I need a quick, drop-in solution, if possible.

Thank you for your responses, though.

Comment: Does `ActiveSheet.Range("A1:B1").Value = arr` make any difference? Explicitly assigning to the `Value` property rather than assigning to whatever the default property happens to be

Comment: @barrowc: It makes no difference. I've tested the .Value, .Value2, .Formula, and .Text attributes, just in case they happened to function differently. None of them emulate 32bit auto-formatting.

Comment: Are you running the script on the same machine with both 32 or 64 bit Excel installed on it? Or on different machines? Are the versions of the 2 installations of Excel exactly the same (apart from the bit part)?

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem like this earlier and resolved it by ensuring that the cell format was always set to a date format.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
Range("A1").Select
Selection.Format = "long date"
```

Comment: Please read the comments to the original question. The poster is aware you can specifically set a format, but not all values are dates; the issue is to **not** have to set the format for individual values in the array.